# OpenLayers behaves problematic after certain zoom level in Google Maps Satellite view

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

I have some polygon data in `.shp` format to show in Google Maps Satellite view. I can show them well until certain zoom level.

[image]

But after certain level (zoom level 17 or 18), `OpenLayers` layer and `Google Maps Satellite` layer displace each other like this.

[image]

We know `Google Maps Satellite` View changes it camera angle after certain zoom level and put it to 45 degrees. How can i resolve this with `OpenLayers`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was recently [fixed](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/1265). If you are not able to use the latest version, you can do the following after adding your Google layer to the map (here: `myGoogleLayer`):

```
myGoogleLayer.mapObject.setTilt(0);
```

Comment: When I add this line `googleSatellite.mapObject.setTilt(0)`, browser shows me this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setTilt' of null`.

Then I add  `tilt: (this.useTiltImages ? 45 : 0)` to map options and nothing changes.

Comment: You have to add the layer to the map before calling `setTilt()` on the `mapObject`. The second attempt you describe does not make sense at all.